# Why are "Batman" and "Superman" both one word but "Spider-Man" is hyphenated?

Tags: marvel, dc, superman, history-of, spider-man

Batman and Superman are always spelt as all one word but Spider-Man is separated into two words.

Is there any reason behind or is it just the way it is?

Comment: DC versus Marvel?

Comment: That would make sense as Superman is also all one word.

Comment: Apples to oranges.

Comment: Maybe this should have been migrated to the English language site, rather than here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Stan Lee has claimed [(e.g., in the set of Twitter posts quoted here)](http://www.spidermancrawlspace.com/wordpress/2010/02/24/spider-mans-hyphen-explained/) that the hyphen is to stop people from confusing Spider-Man with Superman:

> Spidey's official name has a hyphen: "Spider-Man." Know why? When I dreamed him up, I didn't want anyone confusing him with Superman!

Comment: There was also a Spider Man already in existence. http://io9.com/5921849/the-first-spider+man-in-comics-wasnt-peter-parker-but-a-pervert-supervillain

Comment: Or with Phil Spiderman.